# Strange revenue from Ethermine

Tags: mining-pools, ethminer

I noticed that ethermine revenues change with eth's price. 
I expected that revenue were to chage with difficulty's increase, what wrong? It's normal?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where did you notice this change in revenue? And by revenue, did you mean to say the Ether generated from mining?

Comment: I noticed that with a price around $15 with 200MH / h the revenue for a month is about 41 eth . With the price of around $ 10 46 eth and when it fell to around $ 8 50 eth. Continue to fluctuate according to the price.